# How to test for enough variance in Logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, variance

I would like to find out if there's enough variance in my dependent variable which is binary.

Which techniques would be best for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just start with a simple table and look at the proportion of "successes". You could look at the variance, but in a binary variable that is just a function of that proportion. So, the variance contains no extra information on top of that proportion.

After that the main question becomes: Enough for what? One thing you could look into is a power analysis, for more see: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) or [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/power-by-simulation/). The advantage is that this will force you to be very precise in specifying your question.